# How much swap space should I use?

Tags: swap, ram

What rules should I follow to determine how much swap space my linux-based computer should have today?

Comment: It depends. There's an old rule that says “twice as much as RAM”, and while the reason for it is bogus (if you follow the reasoning, it should be “as much as RAM”), it's as good as any. See [Why do we need to set swap space as twice big as our physical memory?](http://superuser.com/questions/187695/why-do-we-need-to-set-swap-space-as-twice-big-as-our-physical-memory/187706#187706)

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to hibernate, you want to have a swap size that is at least the size of your RAM, or it is possible that you will not have enough swap to hibernate at all.

Otherwise, I wouldn't worry too much. Unless you have specific needs, you shouldn't be dipping into swap too much. It is nice to be able to swap out some stuff that is on the LRU lists to make way for more important things (like the filesystem cache, for example), but it's not totally necessary. All you need is to choose a number that you consider high enough to not be reached.

Realistically, your system would probably become slow enough that you would notice if you dipped in there significantly. I set swap to 2GB on all of my desktop systems, since I don't hibernate. Disk space is cheap, I can afford 2GB, but it's probably still excessive for most use cases.

Work out your use case, and go from there. If you're not hibernating, and you're using a desktop, 2GB should be more than enough. You don't really want to be using much, anyway, the only reason that it's wise to have it when not hibernating is to avoid the wrath of the OOM killer (or whatever other method you choose to use when the system is out of usable memory).

Comment: Why would I ever need 2GB swap if I do not intend to hibernate?

Comment: @l3iggs You wouldn't, probably, unless some process starts leaking memory. But space is cheap, anyway, so I like to have some time to realise that something is leaking all over the place, and kill it (here's looking at you, Chromium).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I run all those application at the same time. Then I execute the command `free -m` to check the available memory. If it is almost full then, I create swap space of `half of RAM size`. And then proceed further.

Technically, It was said that Swap space need to be twice of RAM size (Windows Default Behaviour)

Comment: True. But swap twice RAM is a thing of the past when we still used swap. These days both linux and windows use paging. We might still call it a swapfile, but that is just habit and no longer reflect the underlying truth.

Answer (score 0):

I normally have as much Swap as I have RAM.

It will depend on how you use your system though. I barely ever use the swap if I'm just browsing around. It's when I'm gaming with other things open that swap gets used.

If you have lots of memory intensive applications open then you will need more swap than if you just played games all day long (assuming that your computer met the game's memory requirements)

If you are just a light internet user, then chances are you could get away with no swap at all assuming that you have a reasonably recent system.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit about how the answer might change based on different uses of the system?